# log4j does not log for file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am using log4j to log to both console and file. It just works with console, but not with file, **thought the file is being created**

This is my configuration file:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n 

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/my_server_logs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=guru.springframework.blog.log4j2properties
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = file, stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection between file appender and root logger is missing.
Add the following line at the bottom of your properties file:

```
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
```

It will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you expect that the variable ${filename} be substituted with the value of property.filename.

Can you try to substitute ${filename} with a hard path and try again (E.g: 'C:\' on Windows or '/tmp/' on Unix-like).

Comment: the ` ${filename}` is indeed being replaced by `property.filename`, and, as I mentioned in the question, the file is being created